# Algorithm to print asterisks for duplicate characters

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview:
Given an array with the input string, display the output as shown below

**Input**

```
INDIA
```

**Output**

```
INDA  
****  
*
```

I iterated through the array and stored each character as a key in `std::map` with value as number of occurrence. Later I iterate the map and print the asteriks and reduce the value in the map for each character.

Initially, I was asked not to use any library. I gave a solution which needed lot of iterations. For every character, iterate the complete array till the index to find previous occurrences and so on. 
Is there any better way, e.g. better complexity, such as faster operation, by which this can be achieved?

Comment: For the "any better way" you might want to be more specific and actually show the way you did it. Although I think this might then be better suited for codereview.se (ore maybe even codegolf.se sicne no libraries allowed)

Comment: In case the input string is in an 8-bit (or even 16-bit) charset, you could use a simple array or vector to mark encountered characters.

Comment: I don't exactly understand output format, can you elaborate?

Comment: @TejasPatel: Its a histogram of character occurence counts.

Comment: @TejasPatel Each letter has a column with asterisks representing the occurrences in the string.

Comment: "**Initially** I was asked not to use any library". Red flag. The company probably suffers from Not-Invented-Here syndrome. A sane company checks first if new hires will prefer existing libraries, and only then test if they can also come up with workarounds.

Comment: I have written full C++ code and also tested it. Check to see if it works

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have mentioned how did I do it using STL. My question is whether we can do it better without using stl.

Comment: @MSalters This is a perfectly good problem, solvable at an interview in a short amount of time (30 mins, perhaps) which will allow them to demonstrate how they solve problems.  Allowing people to use libraries will discover how well people know the libraries but that might not be what they're looking for; doing it "by hand" is perhaps  better at allowing candidates to demonstrate the way they write code (decomposition, structure, naming etc).   I can't imagine any company seriously expects c++ developers to not use the standard library in their day job.

Comment: @Poldie: It shows how developers solve problems _which they shouldn't be solving in the first place_ !

Comment: can you explain "not to use any library" ? `map` is on an equal footing with `string` and `cout` in this respect.

Comment: @MattMcNabb this was for an interview, not real code. The idea is to test your ability to think of solutions and code standard algorithms if need be. Placing artificial constraints on a problem forces you to do things the hard way.

Comment: I tested my answer and it seems to work well enough. It doesn't handle wide characters nor does it use dynamic arrays but we are not allowed to use the library and rewriting std::string and std::vector isn't very appealing.

Comment: Why does `INDIA` become `INDA`?

Comment: Duplicate characters are removed..

Comment: @codeMagic Why is this question put on hold? This is a valid question with definite answers. Since this is an algorithm question, there can be many different possible ways to solve it. Is that a criteria to put a question on hold?

Comment: @cppcoder This was discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255590/another-invalid-failed-audit?cb=1) on [meta.so].  The meta effect closed it, apparently.  It's now reopened.  If it closes again, I would suggest protecting it and/or flagging for a moderator.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for reopening it.

Comment: @Joe The post is closed again. How can I protect this post from closing without any proper reason?

Comment: You need to flag this for a moderator, or go to chat and discuss with a moderator - they have to lock it, not just normal protect.  Given this was a featured meta post, I'd guess moderators have already looked at this and decided to leave it alone, but you can certainly give it a shot.

Comment: I have already flagged it, but no response.

Comment: Why on earth are the moderators down voting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another one:
You can see it working [HERE](https://ideone.com/eqiBhO)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j=0,f=1;
    char input[50]={'I','N','D','I','A','N','A','N'};
    char letters[256]={0};
    int counter[256]={0};
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        if(input[i])
         counter[input[i]]++;
         if(counter[input[i]]==1)
         {
            putchar(input[i]);
            letters[j]=input[i];
            j++;
         }    
    }
    putchar('\n');
    while(f)
    {
        f=0;      
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
            if(counter[letters[i]])
            {
                putchar('*');
                counter[letters[i]]--;
                f=1;
            }
            else
            {
                putchar(' ');
            }
        putchar('\n');  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some characters have negative values. You should ensure correct indexing.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially what you are asking is how to implement `map` without using the STL code, as using some kind of data structure which replicates the basic functionality of `map` is pretty much the most reasonable way of solving this problem.

There are a number of ways of doing this. If your keys (here the possible characters) come from a very large set where most elements of the set don't appear (such as the full Unicode character set), you would probably want to use either a tree or a hash table. Both of these data structures are very important with lots of variations and different ways of implementing them. There is lots of information and example code about the two structures around.

As @PeterG said in a comment, if the only characters you are going to see are from a set of 256 8-bit chars (eg ASCII or similar), or some other limited collection like the upper-case alphabet you should just use an array of 256 `int`s and store a count for each char in that.

Comment: If you proposed the solution for 8-bit chars, the next question from the interviewer would likely be how to do it for the full Unicode set. And to be honest, if the expected input were all short strings the O(n^2) solution proposed in the question might be the fastest.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think either assuming 8-bit chars or assuming short strings would be a mistake as an interviewee. Bad code tends to be written by people who make those kind of assumptions. At the very least state 'First, I will work under the simplifying assumption...', solve the problem, then drop the assumption and solve the general problem.

Comment: Note that the input is an array, not a string of chars, @Veritas. Whatever type the array is of, presumably one could have a map with keys of the same type?

Comment: Sorry it's late, I got confused somehow. Should it be expected of him to also need to handle wide characters? He would have to write a string class to handle the input and then re-implement a map. It seems like too much for an interview question.

Comment: It's an array! Every single other answer has assumed that there are few enough chars in the alphabet for an array to be adequate. I think understanding that this might not be the case, and knowing how to implement an alternative, are exactly what an interviewer might be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If the alphabet under consideration is fixed, it can be done in two passes:

1. Create an integer array A with the size of the alphabet, initialized with all zeros.
2. Create a boolean array B with size of the input, initialize with all false.
3. Iterate the input; increase for every character the corresponding content of A.
4. Iterate the input; output a character if its value it B is false and set its value in B to true. Finally, output a carriage return.
5. Reset B.
6. Iterate input as in 4., but print a star if if the character's count in A is positive, then decrease this count; print a space otherwise.
7. Output a carriage return; loop to 5 as long as there are any stars in the output generated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works correctly. I am assuming that you can't use std::string and take note that this doesn't take overflowing into account since I didn't use dynamic containers. This also assumes that the characters can be represented with a char.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char input[100];
    unsigned int input_length = 0;
    char letters[100];
    unsigned int num_of_letters = 0;
    std::cin >> input;
    while (input[input_length] != '\0')
    {
        input_length += 1;
    }
    //This array acts like a hash map.
    unsigned int occurrences[256] = {0};
    unsigned int max_occurrences = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_length; ++i)
    {
        if ((occurrences[static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i])] += 1) == 1)
        {
            std::cout<< " " << (letters[num_of_letters] = input[i]) << " ";
            num_of_letters += 1;
        }
        if (occurrences[static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i])] > max_occurrences)
        {
            max_occurrences = occurrences[static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i])];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int row = 1; row <= max_occurrences; ++row)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_letters; ++i)
        {

            if (occurrences[static_cast<unsigned char>(letters[i])] >= row)
            {
                std::cout << " * ";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "   ";
            }

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. You shouldnt use a stl::map because that is not a hashmap. An stl map is a binary tree. An unordered_map is actually a hash map. In this case we dont need either. We can use a simple array for char counts.

```
void printAstr(std::string str){
 int array[256] ;// assumining it is an ascii string
 memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
 int astrCount = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
     array[(int) str[i]]++;
     if(array[(int) str[i]] > 1) astrCount++;
 }
std::cout << str  << std::endl;
for(int i = 0;  i < str.length()-1;i++) std::cout << "* ";
std::cout << std::endl;
while(astrCount != 0){
   for(int i= 0; i< str.length() - 1;i++){
       if(array[(int) str[i]] > 1){
          std::cout << "* ";
          array[(int) str[i]]--;
          astrCount--;
       }else{
        std::cout << " ";
       }
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

}

pretty simple just add all values to the array, then print them out the number of times you seem them.

EDIT: sorry just made some logic changes. This works now.

Comment: It never when into negative values. But I did have some small logic errors which I just fixed

Comment: The string could contain negative chars, e.g. `é`

Comment: I said in the comment `//assuming ascii string`

Comment: Your comment "_stl map is a binary tree_" is not entirely accurate.    The standard doesn't dictate that a `std::map` be implemented as a binary tree.  It only requires logarithmic lookup complexity, which is why it is often implemented with a [Red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) under-the-hood.

Comment: @Void Yes, but look you said "there is a rb-tree under the hood" so I am not wrong either. Regardless the point I was trying to make was that you don't need a std::map when you can use a array as a basic hashtable.

Comment: @Jay My point was that the RB tree thing is an implementation detail, which the spec doesn't mandate.  You implied otherwise.  We can argue semantics ad nauseum, but I get what you were trying to say overall.  I was just nitpicking.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is marked as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) but It seems to me that the answers not are all quite *C++'ish*, but could be quite difficult to achieve a good C++ code with a weird requirement like "*not to use any library*". In my approach I've used some *cool* C++11 features like in-class initialization or `nullptr`, [here](http://ideone.com/VvpguU) is the live demo and below the code:

```
struct letter_count
{
    char letter = '\0';
    int count = 0;
};

int add(letter_count *begin, letter_count *end, char letter)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        if (begin->letter == letter)
        {
            return ++begin->count;
        }
        else if (begin->letter == '\0')
        {
            std::cout << letter; // Print the first appearance of each char
            ++begin->letter = letter;
            return ++begin->count;
        }

        ++begin;
    }

    return 0;
}

int max (int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

letter_count *buffer = nullptr;

auto testString = "supergalifragilisticoespialidoso";

int len = 0, index = 0, greater = 0;

while (testString[index++])
    ++len;

buffer = new letter_count[len];

for (index = 0; index < len; ++index)
    greater = max(add(buffer, buffer + len, testString[index]), greater);

std::cout << '\n';

for (int count = 0; count < greater; ++count)
{
    for (index = 0; buffer[index].letter && index < len; ++index)
        std::cout << (count < buffer[index].count ? '*' : ' ');

    std::cout << '\n';
}

delete [] buffer;
```

Since "no libraries are allowed" (except for `<iostream>`?) I've avoided the use of `std::pair<char, int>` (which could have been the `letter_count` struct) and we have to code many utilities (such as `max` and `strlen`); the output of the program avobe is:

```
supergaliftcod
**************
* *******   * 
*     ***   * 
*       *     
        *     
        *
```

Answer (score 1):

My general solution would be to traverse the word and replace repeated characters with an unused nonsense character.  A simple example is below, where I used an exclamation point (!) for the nonsense character (the input could be more robust, some character that is not easily typed, disallowing the nonsense character in the answer, error checking, etc).  After traversal, the final step would be removing the nonsense character.  The problem is keeping track of the asterisks while retaining the original positions they imply.  For that I used a temp string to save the letters and a process string to create the final output string and the asterisks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  string input = "";
  string tempstring = "";
  string process = "";
  string output = "";
  bool test = false;

  cout << "Enter your word below: " << endl;
  cin >> input;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.length (); i++)
  { //for the traversed letter, traverse through subsequent letters    
    for (unsigned int z = i + 1; z < input.length (); z++)
    {
        //avoid analyzing nonsense characters
        if (input[i] != '!')    
        {           
          if (input[i] == input[z]) 
          { //matched letter; replace with nonsense character
            input[z] = '!';
            test = true;    //for string management later
          }
        }
    }
    if (test)   
    {
      tempstring += input[i];
      input[i] = '*';
      test = false; //reset bool for subsequent loops
    }
  }

  //remove garbage symbols and save to a processing string
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size (); i++)
    if (input[i] != '!')
      process += input[i];

  //create the modified output string
  unsigned int temp = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < process.size (); i++)
    if (process[i] == '*')
    { //replace asterisks with letters stored in tempstring
      output += tempstring[temp];
      temp++;
    }
    else
      output += process[i];

   //output word with no repeated letters
  cout << output << endl;

  //output asterisks equal to output.length
  for (unsigned int a = 0; a < output.length (); a++)
    cout << "*";

  cout << endl;

  //output asterisks for the letter instances removed
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < process.size (); i++)      
    if (process[i] != '*')
      process[i] = ' ';

  cout << process << endl << endl;
}
```

Sample output I received by running the code:

```
Enter your word below: 
INDIA
INDA
****
*

Enter your word below: 
abcdefgabchijklmnop
abcdefghijklmnop
****************
***
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible just using simple array to keep count of values.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string s;
    char arr[10000];
    cin>>s;
    int count1[256]={0},count2[256]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i){
        count1[s[i]]++;
        count2[s[i]]++;
    }
    long max=-1;
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();++i){
        if(count1[s[i]]==count2[s[i]]){ //check if not printing duplicate
            cout<<s[i]; 
            arr[j++]=s[i];
        }
        if(count2[s[i]]>max)
            max=count2[s[i]];
        --count1[s[i]];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i =1; i<=max;++i){
        for(int k=0;k<j;++k){
            if(count2[arr[k]]){
                cout<<"*";
                count2[arr[k]]--;
            }
            else
                cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: Who ever downvoted, please give reason.

Comment: Line 6,7,12,16,17,18,23,25 out-of-bounds access. Line 14, out of bounds access after a while. Final loop, trailing spaces don't seem appropriate. Wall of hard-to-read, unexplained code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the code works perfectly fine, try on ur machine and vote. I know I kept char array size fixed but it was demonstration only, op can figure it out. It worked for him so why do u bother

Comment: On my system the negative chars cause a garbage line to be printed (although anything could happen, since it is undefined behaviour to access outside an array's bounds)

Comment: @MattMcNabb what do u mean by negative char? And how can some char have 0 count? Only char in string are considered so u have understood something different

Comment: Sorry, actually it does print the right number of stars. Negative chars are chars whose value is less than `0`. On typical systems `char` ranges from `-128` to `+127`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52717/discussion-between-tejas-patel-and-matt-mcnabb)

Comment: @TejasPatel 'try on ur machine' is not an adequate explanation of your code in an interview setting.